Retrieving the individuals belonging to an imported class
I created a local ontology that imports another ontology located on the web (I used Protégé). Is there a way in OWL-API to get the individuals of a class of the imported ontology?
I tried the following
ontology.individualsInSignature(Imports.INCLUDED).forEach((i) -> {
            EntitySearcher.getTypes(i, ontology).forEach((c) -> {
                // check if c is your imported class --> select i
            });
        });

but the result set is empty.
I guess that EntitySearcher.getTypes(...) does not find the facts in the local ontology, and I have not found a way to force getType(...) to search across the imported ontology.
Any ideas?

Can you add the data you're using, i.e., the two ontologies, or example ontologies that reproduce the problem? Your code seems correct.

An empty local ontology that imports the wine ontology ( http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/PR-owl-guide-20031209/wine). If I ask for the class "Region" individuals, my code returns an empty result set.
